# How can i get last ListCell in ListView?

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have started making a program in JavaFX where i have ListView with added functionality like editing, adding new items and deleting.I have managed to do most of the work but there is still a little more to do. So far i have added the deleting and editing functionality successfully but i have got a small problem with the adding functionality. I can still add new items to the ListView but i can't make it possible to edit the newly added item, because i need the ListCell the new item represents to start editing it. So my question is how can i get the ListCell of the new item in the ListView.

For this purpose here is my code:

```
    private TextField textField;
    ListCell<String> cell = this;
    int i = 0;
    boolean manually_selected = false;


    public LanguageListCell(ListView<String> languages) 
    {

        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();


        cell.setEditable(true);



        MenuItem editItem = new MenuItem();
        editItem.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Edit \"%s\"", cell.itemProperty()));

        editItem.setOnAction(event -> {

            // The LanguageListCell class i want to put here...
            cell.startEdit();
        });

        MenuItem addItem = new MenuItem("Add language");

        addItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent> () {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent ev)
            {


                i++;

                String lang = "New Language " + i;



                languages.getItems().add(lang);



                if(i == 10)
                {

                    addItem.setDisable(true);
                }
                languages.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                languages.getSelectionModel().select(languages.getItems().size() - 1);
                cell.setItem(languages.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

                manually_selected = true;



            }



        });


        MenuItem deleteItem = new MenuItem();
        deleteItem.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Delete \"%s\"", cell.itemProperty()));
        deleteItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent> () {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent ev)
            {
                if(languages.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size() - 1 > 0)
                {

                    if(i > 0)
                    {
                        i = (languages.getItems().size() - languages.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size()) - 1;
                    }
                    /*for(String lang: languages.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems())
                    {
                        languages.getItems().remove(lang);

                    }*/
                    ArrayList<String> delete_data = new ArrayList<String>(languages.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
                    languages.getItems().removeAll(delete_data);

                }
                languages.getItems().remove(cell.getItem());
                if(i > 0) i = 0;
            }

        });

        contextMenu.setOnShowing(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent e) {
                if(languages.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size() - 1 > 0)
                {
                    editItem.setDisable(true);
                    addItem.setDisable(true);
                }
            }
         });

        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(addItem, editItem, deleteItem);

        cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());

        cell.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> {
            if (isNowEmpty) {
                cell.setContextMenu(null);
            } else {

                cell.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

            }
        });



    }
```

Comment: Just a guess here: It seems like you are doing your code inside of the `Cell`. I am guessing you can say something like `languages.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().remove(this)` or set the cell's text and/or graphic to `null`. Just a guess.

Comment: Ah yes I will update it right away. But do you have any idea how to get the ListCell at the last index in the ListView ?

Comment: It's something like `languages.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().get(languages.getItems().size() - 1)`, but if you are in the `ListCell` `this` should repersent the current `ListCell` you are in.`

Comment: Ye that should be it, but after i add a new item to the listview the cell is the same as the one i selected previously. So in this case I dont know what should be the solution. I need the last listcell for my custom startEdit method. That's why.

Comment: Look at how to create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I could probably be more help then.

Comment: Ok now i will be more clear. What I'm after is after i select the addItem MenuItem a new item is being added to the ListView. In that case i want after this item is added to select it and initialize the startEdit method over it, which is custom method included in this class which i posted. So in this case i select the new item but i cant get the ListCell representing it. If i have the ListCell i could do something like this : cell.startEdit(). My only problem is with the ListCell because i dont have any idea how to get it.

Comment: You should start the edit via `ListView` and index. (You should be able to determine the index where you insert the item easily.) The problem with "getting the `ListCell`" is that there may not be a `ListCell` associated with a given item. If the item's cell would be displayed outside of the viewport of the `ListView` this is highly likely.

Comment: don't even think "get cell" with any of the virtualized controls - it's not supported. Period. And for good reason (as @fabian already noted). As to your requirement: there are issues with starting an edit on the a newly added item, search this forum to get an idea about options to hack around.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help !